# logstash - Unable to parse timestamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have the following JSON log (new line separated )

```
{
      "logName": "projects/gg-sanbox/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request",
      "timestamp": "2018-04-02 22:26:02.869 UTC",
      "receiveTimestamp":"2018-04-02 22:28:06.742394 UTC",
}
```

and logstash config

```
input
    {
      file {
        type => "json"
        path => "/logs/mylogs.log"
        codec => json
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
    }

    filter{
        json{
            source => "message"
        }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"]
    }
    }

    output
    {
        stdout
        {
            #codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch
        {
        codec => "json_lines"
            hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
           # document_id => "%{logstash_checksum}"
            index => "appengine_nginx-requests"
        }

    }
```

I am getting the following in the logstash output

```
"@timestamp"=>2018-04-07T15:26:31.857Z, "tags"=>["_dateparsefailure"],
```

Notice that its falling back to the current data and time instead of the time mentioned in the log line which is actually the event had occured and I want to see in the Kibana timeline.

Not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: You mean I need to use gork before using this filter? Since its json I know where exactly is the timestamp key. There are multiple datetime fields so matching by pattern may result in matching multiple fields.

Comment: as in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS UTC ? BTW all my timestamps would be in UTC

Comment: I was just taking time to try it out. UTC inside quote worked. Most of the document matched but looks like some of them has 6 digit (microseconds) which did not match. Guess that deserves a different SoF question. You may please 'UTC' as answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am ok to lose the precision but can I somehow match it in a "fallback" filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [date filter plugin documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), the format option `Z` does not match `UTC`; because alone it's not a timezone (for it to be valid it would need to be `+0000`). You'll need to add it like so: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'`

To answer your other question about the precision of the seconds; it's simply **not supported** to have any precision lower than milliseconds. If you look at link above, you'll find:

> Maximum precision is milliseconds (SSS). Beyond that, zeroes are appended.